# docker-compose down won't work, looking for a network that doesn't exist, nor did i create

Tags: docker, docker-compose

here is my compose file:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  plex:
    domainname: xxxx.com
    hostname: dstation
    image: plexinc/pms-docker:latest
    environment:
      - PLEX_CLAIM=xxxxxxx
      - ADVERTISE_IP="http://xxxxxx:32400/"
      - PLEX_UID=1030
      - PLEX_GID=65537
      - TZ=America/New_York #optional
    ports:
      - "32400:32400"
      - "3005:3005"
      - "8324:8324"
      - "32469:32469"
      - "1900:1900"
      - "32410:32410"
      - "32412:32412"
      - "32413:32413"
      - "32414:32414"
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/plex/config:/config
      - /volume1/docker/plex/transcode:/transcode
      - /volume1/FamilyPhotos:/data/photos-family
      - /volume1/JoePhotos:/data/photos-joe
      - /volume1/mediad/Movies:/data/movies
      - /volume1/mediad/TV:/data/tv
      - /volume1/mediad/Movies-Kids:/data/movies-kids
      - /volume1/mediad/Videos:/data/videos
    restart: unless-stopped

  unifi:
    domainname: xxxxx.com
    hostname: dstation
    image: linuxserver/unifi-controller
    container_name: unifi
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      - PUID=1031
      - PGID=100
    volumes:
      - /volume1/docker/unifi/config:/config
    # ports:
    # - 3478:3478/udp
    # - 10001:10001/udp
    # - 8080:8080
    # - 8443:8443
    # - 1900:1900/udp #optional
    # - 8843:8843 #optional
    # - 8880:8880 #optional
    # - 6789:6789 #optional
    # - 5514:5514 #optional
    restart: unless-stopped
```

when i try to `docker-compose down` i get this output and it doesn't go down:

```
Removing network dstation-docker_default
WARNING: Network dstation-docker_default not found.
```

not sure why its looking for that network and i don't know how to get past it

i can stop the containers, but i can't have it go down.

btw, on a synology diskstation, but i don't think its relevant as im using the commandline.

Comment: Compose automatically creates a network named `default` and attaches containers to it, absent other configuration; your `plex` container is implicitly using it.  More details are in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems project-name has changed between up and down.

Avoid this situation by not changing directory name where `docker-compose.yml` is located, between docker-compose up and down commands.

Also consider, if you ran something like `docker-compose --project-name NAME up -d`, then you should specify project-name in `docker-compose --project-name NAME down` too.

Use `docker network ls` to list all networks, and remove the ones not needed anymore with `docker network remove NAME`.